# How to fix stopping loop in following code

Tags: python, json, function, python-requests

I'm working at parser. Loop breaks after exception. Need ur help

```py
def requestBarter():
    response = requests.get(api url)
    return response.json();


def responsePrint(id, json_data):
    title = json_data[id]["title"]
    tradable = json_data[id]["tradable"]
    wishlist = json_data[id]["wishlist"]
    library = json_data[id]["library"]
    bundles = json_data[id]["bundles"]
    cards = json_data[id]["cards"]
    userreviews = json_data[id]["userreviews"]
    print("ID: " + id + " | Titile: " + title + " | Tradable: " + str(tradable) + " | Wishlist: " + str(
        wishlist) + " | Library: " + str(
        library) + " | Bundles: " + str(bundles) + " | Cards: " + str(cards) + " | Userreviews: " + str(userreviews))

def responsePrintOnException(id, json_data):
    title = json_data[id]["title"]
    tradable = json_data[id]["tradable"]
    wishlist = json_data[id]["wishlist"]
    library = json_data[id]["library"]
    bundles = json_data[id]["bundles"]
    cards = json_data[id]["cards"]
    print("ID: " + id + " | Titile: " + title + " | Tradable: " + str(tradable) + " | Wishlist: " + str(
        wishlist) + " | Library: " + str(
        library) + " | Bundles: " + str(bundles) + " | Cards: " + str(cards))


def getAll():
    try:
        json_data = requestBarter()
        for id in json_data:
            responsePrint(id, json_data)
    except KeyError:
        responsePrintOnException(id, json_data)
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    getAll()
```

After KeyError getting out of loop so need help in the following code
Expected over 90000 lines. actual output - 30

Comment: right now `id` is local to the `for` loop, define `id` outside of the try `id=0` and that may help, though your functions look near identical

Comment: if you want to continue the loop after the exception, you will have to catch the exception inside the loop.